# check type of object given by a string in python

Tags: python, object, types

I would like to ask how one determines the type of an object in python. I know how to do that "normally", e.g.,

```
import types

def f(x):
    return x

isinstance(f, types.FunctionType)
```

returns true. But what, if I have only a string containing 'f', say a = 'f'. What should I do with a? How do I figure out, whether the object specified by a string is a function, or whatever? And before anyone asks, it is a parser, and that is why I don't know whether 'f' is a function;)

Thanks,

v923z

Comment: Why do you get strings specifying Python objects in your namespace when you write a parser? Or did I misunderstand you? Elaboration on why you think you need this would be interesting.

Comment: Nane, could you, please, tell me what I am supposed to do with the type function? type(a) will return <type 'str'>. I have already known that...

Comment: delnan, I am not sure I understand your question: I have a command line, the parser takes lines from there, and then parses the string. If, e.g., the first word is a number, I want to do this, if it is a function, I want to do that. I really don't see, how I can bypass strings in this case.

Comment: Fine, but why do you mix up whatever namespace the identifiers from the command line belong to with the namespace of your Python code? You probably don't want the local variables of the parsing function to be exposed, do you?

Comment: No, I don't. But how should I separate the two?

Comment: Simply use a dedicated dictionary (instead of a Python scope) for the command line's namespace? You can populate it with everything you want to make available, and users can add new stuff without messing with your variables. You can also chain several dictionaries together if you want stuff like nested scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up the name in `globals()` (the global symbol table and `locals()` (the local symbol table):

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(x):
...     return x
... 
>>> globals()['f']
<function f at 0x1004c0230>
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(globals()['f'], types.FunctionType)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To know its type you can to evaluate it from string to its real representation:

```
def f(x):
    return x

a = "f"
aEvaluated = eval(a)
print(type(aEvaluated))
isinstance(aEvaluated, types.FunctionType)
```

Comment: No. That's the only way (save minor variations that do basically the same thing) to know the result of an arbitrary Python expression. That's far more than OP needs or wants.

Answer (score 0):

If "f" refers to a variable in the local environment, use can use *globals()* to look it up:

```
>>> def f(x):
        return x

>>> a = 'f'
>>> type(globals()[a])
<type 'function'>
```